# Cannot use import statement outside a module when run my typescript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, rabbitmq

I am writing a "Hello world" RabbitMQ project in typescript. I am using Yarn as package management tool instead of NPM.

I have installed the RabbitMQ client library [amqplib](https://yarnpkg.com/package/amqplib) & its type definition. My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "rabbitmq-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/publisher.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
 
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/amqplib": "^0.8.0",
    "amqplib": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` has following options enabled:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es2016", 
   "module": "commonjs",
   "rootDir": "./src",
   "outDir": "./dist",
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
   "strict": true,  
   "skipLibCheck": true
 }
}
```

My `./src/publishier.ts`, you don't need to care about the logic in the code for my question, I just want to indicate I have this typescript file I wrote:

```
import * as amqp from "amqplib";

const msg = {number: 6};

const connect = async () => {
    try {
        const connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost:5673");
        const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    
        const queue = await channel.assertQueue("jobs"); // create queue named "jobs"
        channel.sendToQueue("jobs", Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg)));
        console.log(`Job sent successfully! ${msg.number}`);


    } catch(e) {

    }
    
}

connect();
```

When I run `node src/publisher.ts`, I get error:

```
import * as amqp from "amqplib";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Then I added `"type": "module"` in `package.json` & run again, but get new error:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /rabbitmq-demo/src/publisher.ts
```

So, what is the root cause of the problems? How to run my `publisher.ts`?

Comment: You are asking `nodejs` to execute a `ts` file, instead you should be asking it to execute a `js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are asking `nodejs` to execute a `ts` file, instead...

1. Either we ask `nodejs` to execute the `js` file generated after building the source
2. Or, we should ask `ts-node` to execute the `ts` file

We can try with following `scripts` in `package.json`...

```
{
  "name": "rabbitmq-demo"",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/publisher.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "@types/amqplib": "^0.8.0",
    "amqplib": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "exec": "node dist/publisher.js",
    "preexec": "npm run build",
    "execwithargs": "node dist/publisher.js 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3'",
    "preexecwithargs": "npm run build"
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "ts-node src/publisher.ts",
    "startwithargs": "ts-node src/publisher.ts 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3'"
  }
}
```

Having those scripts in `package.json` and assuming the `outDir` set in `tsconfig.json` is `dist`, we can execute by issuing any of the following on the terminal...

1. `npm run exec`   <--- This will execute via compile and run `js` file
2. `npm run exec 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3'` <--- Run with command-line args
3. `npm run start`  <--- This will execute via `ts-node` using the `ts` file
4. `npm run start 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3'`  <--- Run with command-line args

Comment: Thanks!  Now my publisher.ts code also accept user input from terminal via `process.argv[2]`, how can I pass user input in the "script" of package.json then?

Comment: Have edited the answer. Take a look please. If you can keep the args in `package.json`, then take a look at the additional scripts that I have added. If not, take a look at the below secrion.